# How to blacklist some scsi devices via a kernel parameter?

Tags: scsi, kernel-parameters

I need to tell kernel to completely ignore some SCSI devices (eg. from vendor 'PURE'). I see `libata.force=x.yy:disable` can be used for individual SATA devices, but I need something equivalent for SCSI devices. Any idea? (Via `scsi_mod.dev_flags` ???)

```
$ modinfo scsi_mod | grep dev_flags: | fmt -w 80
parm:           dev_flags:Given scsi_dev_flags=vendor:model:flags[,v:m:f] add
black/white list entries for vendor and model with an integer value of flags
to the scsi device info list (string) parm:           default_dev_flags:scsi
default device flag uint64_t value (ullong)
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need to have the device blacklisted at **boot** time ? I mean you can't wait for init time and echo 1 > /sys/bus/scsi/devices/<device>/delete ? I just ask since trying to solve my problem ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/703779/how-to-stop-prevent-scsi-kthreads-from-handling-some-sata-ports ) I carefully went through all scsi related linux-5.4 boot parameters and… in vain.

Comment: My whole story is that there is a cluster with shared disks and during upgrade the "installer" had bug and while discovering root fs it was mounting r/o but without 'norecovery' :( so journal got rewind and the other node which was using r/w the filesystem was not happy. Thus I'm looking for a solution as kernel param to exclude any sw or human issue later...

Comment: It seems `scsi_mod.dev_flags` could do it but I don't know how to interpret value for `<flags>`, that is value for `<vendor>:<model>:<flags>`. Probably should be BLIST_REPORTLUN2|BLIST_TRY_VPD_PAGES? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/scsi/scsi_devinfo.h